# No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp() -Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

I'm developing a note-taking app (Android app) that uses Firebase, So I intend to add Firebase Authentication. I created the app on Firebase console.

I'm taking an error, as you can see at the image down below:

[image: This is the error message]

I tried some fixes, that I found at Stack Overflow.

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

This is the main function in `main.dart`

I guess I'm missing a spot. But I can't find it.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you configure it in FireBase?

Comment: Also need to make it a future. Put Future<void> async

Comment: I put Future but same error occurred. And yes I configured Firebase, activated sign up with email and password method, I did what Firebase wants.

Comment: Possibly very similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67368311/flutter-web-no-firebase-app-default-has-been-created-call-firebase-app-i/67390821#67390821 (just differing in platform)

Answer (score 1):

For Flutter android if you are initializing Firebase with just

```dart
Firebase.initializeApp();
```

without passing any arguments to the `initializeApp` function (i.e. firebase configuration/api keys of your project), then you need to add the `google-services.json` inside the `android/app/` folder and add some code in `build.gradle` files so the app knows where to take project configuration from.

The recommended way though is to use the [flutterfire_cli](https://pub.dev/packages/flutterfire_cli) package to handle downloading all the necessary configuration files and adding required code to initialize Firebase for your flutter app.

Follow these steps:

1. Go to https://console.firebase.google.com/
2. Select your project
3. On the project overview page you would see a `Add app` button

[image: Firebase console add app button]

4. Click on it and choose the Flutter option

[image]

5. Then follow the step shown on screen and you'll be good

Answer (score 0):

do you have firebase_core dependencie in your pubspec.yaml??
if not : install firebase_core and import it in your main file.

Comment: import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:notable/screens/note_screen.dart';
import 'package:notable/screens/main_screen.dart';
import 'package:notable/screens/signup_screen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' as auth;

Future <void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

Comment: dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_svg: ^1.1.6
  firebase_core: ^2.2.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.1.2
  firebase_dart: ^1.0.11
  cloud_firestore: ^4.0.5